# How to interpret $ \vec{v} \in [0,1]^{N+1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to interpret $\vec{v} \in[0,1]^{N+1}$

Dose it mean a vector of size $N+1$ where the values inside are between $0$ and $1$? or is it a binary vector?

Answer (score 1):

First interpretation is correct.

In second case it should be writen like this $\{0,1\}^{N+
1}$ or  $ \mathbb{Z}_2^{N+1}$ or $\mathbb{F}_2^{N+1}$

Comment: Was it helpfull?